# Cloud Functions for Firebase: How to read/write to database as an existing user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I like to use firebase functions to test firebase rules I defined.

I would like to read/write to realtime database as an existing user to test if the rules work as expected.

I read in [getting started page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started), I can write to realtime database as admin as follow:
`admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: 'some text'});`

How can I do the same as a user I have created in firebase instead of as admin?

Comment: What kind of function are you writing?  A database trigger?

Comment: Hi Doug, I want to write a Http function; the function will write to Realtime Database as a user I already created. Base the return result, I can find if the rule I defined is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I believe when you get the **Delta Snapshot** from the triggered event that the current state of that snapshot is tied to the user.  Since the Firebase team is providing you with the server-less environment, they attach the admin as well since it's in a secure location.

So just grabbing the **ref** from the current snapshot, should give you the ability to test the database rules.  Just to clarify, I am talking about the `snapshot.ref`, and not the `snapshot.adminRef`.

Here is the reference from their [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot#ref):

> Returns a Reference to the Database location where the triggering write occurred. This Reference has the same end-user permissions as the client that did the write. So, if an unauthenticated client did the write, this Reference is unauthenticated. If the client that did the write is authenticated as a certain Firebase Auth user, this Reference is authenticated as that same user.

Comment: Thanks JamWils. I want to be able to write to Realtime Database as an existing user I have created. Then from the returned result (the callback / promise), I can find out if the security rule I defined works.

Comment: Yes, using the **Delta Snapshot** from the event and grabbing that ref, should have the user's permission.  That is what I was referring to when I wrote `snapshot.ref`.  In the case of the event coming in, I think you're looking for `event.data.ref`.